Query all transaction history via BigTable / not going through RPC?
I'm looking to collect full transaction history for my personal wallets, due to some bot trading there are a large number of transactions.
I'm currently using getSignaturesForAddress/getParsedTransactions but due to RPC issues I'm not certain I'm collecting all the data.
I understand that Solana's full history is stored somehow, somewhere on Google BigTable? Is there a way I can write a SQL query directly on that database?

Yes you can do that using https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery. There are multiple public data sets:
solana-data-sandbox.crypto_solana_mainnet_us.Accounts
bigquery-public-data.crypto_solana_mainnet_us.Accounts
bigquery-public-data.crypto_solana_mainnet_us.Transactions
You can find the data sets here: https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/bigquery-public-data/crypto-solana-mainnet-us
